# REST Web service JSON format

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a REST web service that returns the details of a user.

Here is my code:

```
//Actual web service methods implemented from here
    @GET
    @Path("login/{email}/{password}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Tourist loginUser(@PathParam("email") String email, @PathParam("password") String password) {
        List<Tourist> tourists = super.findAll();
        for (Tourist tourist : tourists) {
            if (tourist.getEmail().equals(email) && tourist.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                return tourist;
            }
        }
        //if we got here the login failed
        return null;
    }
```

This produces the following JSON:

```
{
    "email": "adrian.olar@email.ro",
    "fname": "Adrian",
    "lname": "Olar",
    "touristId": 1
}
```

What i need is:

```
    {"tourist":{
            "email": "adrian.olar@email.ro",
            "fname": "Adrian",
            "lname": "Olar",
            "touristId": 1
        }
    }
```

What would i need to add to my code to produce this?

Comment: That's not a valid JSON so you can't without violating the spec. Are you sure that's exactly what you want?

Comment: This is not a REST service. Where are the links in the json?

Comment: @inf3rno Links are not necessary for REST.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just intended as an example, but you should *never* submit password information over GET, as it will get cached and inspected.

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria You are terribly wrong.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS
REST should always return hypermedia, not just plain data.

Comment: @inf3rno I know about HATEOS. But are you implying that JAX-RS returning JSON is not REST?

Comment: JAX-RS is a framework, you can write REST and non REST APIs with that, depending on how you communicate your controllers. If your client builds them, then it is not REST, if your service sends abstract controllers to the client, and the client is something like a browser, than it is REST.

Comment: @AdrianOlar I recommend you to use [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/), not just a simple JSON format, and send links with your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to wrap a `Tourist` into another object, you can do this.

`Tourist.java`:

```
package entities;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Tourist {

    int touristId;
    String email;
    String fname;
    String lname;
```

`TouristWrapper.java`:

```
package entities;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class TouristWrapper {

    Tourist tourist;
```

`SOResource.java`:

```
package rest;

import entities.Tourist;
import entities.TouristWrapper;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/so")
public class SOResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/tourists/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public TouristWrapper loginUser(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        Tourist tourist = new Tourist(id, "foo@example.com", "John", "Doe");
        TouristWrapper touristWrapper = new TouristWrapper(tourist);
        return touristWrapper;
    }
}
```

I have simplified your usecase but you get the point: No `Tourist` is returned but a `TouristWrapper`. The JSON returned is this:

```
{
    "tourist": {
        "email": "foo@example.com",
        "fname": "John",
        "lname": "Doe",
        "touristId": 1
    }
}
```